# Which time complexity is faster (V^2 + E) or (E log V)

Tags: performance, graph, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have a graph with a large amount of edges to vertices `n(n-1)/2`. If I have 16 verticies `16^2 + 120`  is `376` and `120 * log2(16)` is `480`. So here `V^2` is faster? Is my calculations correct and if they are when will the size of vertices reach the point to `E log v` being faster?

Comment: Remember, asymptotic analysis is not necessarily used to measure a time for a specific input. It's used to measure how things would behave if your inputs would start tending towards infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assymptotic notation informs you about how execution time grows with growing input, and that does not let you do such comparisons like "for `V = 10, E = 15` I get that value smaller than the other".

If you have two algorithms, with time complexities  `O(V^2 + E)` and `O(E log V)`, the only thing you can say is that the first one works better for dense graphs and the other for sparse graphs (by supposing `V^2 = E` for dense and `V = E` for sparse).

Comment: Brilliant! thank you, would you suggest a graph with n(n-1)/2 edges is dense?

Comment: Yes, `O(n(n-1)/2) = O(n^2)`, so it is dense.